# MOSFET load switch design review

Tags: mosfet

Is there any problem with the below circuit for controlling power supply (as a load switch)?

[image: Switching power supply to load control]

Hi,
I am using this circuit to switch power supply to a load. I have gone through the datasheets and this looks likes it is okay. But, could someone please confirm if the the circuit used is alright?

*The load current does not exceed 10A. The load can be a resistive load or a power supply to another module (not an inductive load).*

(I know the MOSFET I used is rated for very high currents).
There is no strict requirement on the switching frequency (less than 1Hz) .
The supply voltage is 9V-12.6V. The control voltage is 3.3V.

EDIT: [pdf datasheet links]

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG6602SVTQ.pdf

https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/FDD8896_F085-D-1806946.pdf

Comment: Whatever you connect to that 2 pin connector (HTR) will always be applied to that R40 resistor, which I assume is your load. In this schematic Q2 would do nothing. I think you meant to connect pin 1 of HTR to your circuit GND. (unless you're using R40 as a shunt?)

Comment: @Stiddily check again.

Comment: The DMG6602 is not recommended for new designs so why use it? Are you not worried about shoot-thru in the DMG? Add PDF data sheet links please. State what the supply voltages are and the control voltage too.

Comment: @Andyaka I could not find any indication on mouser or digikey, regarding the NRND for this part. If it is NRND, is there any alternative for this? Yes, shoot through is definitely a problem, is there anything you recommend to overcome this ?

Comment: Always check with the manufacturer - the mouser data sheet is way out of date. https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/DMG6602SVT.pdf but there is a replacement listed.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks a lot. I will use the alternative suggested. Luckily the footprint is not different. :) Any suggestions regarding the design itself? As you suggested there will be a certain amount of issue regarding the shoot through for transient switching. Is there any way I can make the design better?

Comment: What's the load?

Comment: Read my comments and supply the information. Ditto what winny says. Concentrate on what people ask. What switching speed?

Comment: I have edited my question to add the above information. Please let me know, if any other info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: The devil will be in the details here: _”or a power supply to another module”_. How will that module handle no ground yet Vsupply being present? What’s connected downstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The control voltage is 3.3V*

### The main problem

The gate activation voltage for Q7 is only 3.3 volts!

It will not turn-off the PMOSFET inside Q7 and the circuit will be permanently energized.

Or, ditch the dual MOSFET device (Q7) and use a BJT in common emitter with a load resistor of circa 1 kohm (aka a level shifter). General idea: -

[image]

This can only realistically be overcome with either a control voltage that matches the supply voltage (9 volts to 12.6 volts) or by using an extra input transistor forming a level shifter. This is a show-stopper until fixed. The words below assume it has been fixed.

Given this: -

> *There is no strict requirement on the switching frequency (less than
> 1Hz)*

Using a level shifter isn't going to be a problem.

### The secondary problem

Always check with the manufacturer's website to see if the a device is not recommended for future designs and if so, is an alternative available: -

[image]

However, given that this device is probably best replaced with the common emitter level shifter shown earlier, this is moot.

### Shoot-through problem

This can be overcome by using a 100 Ω resistor in series with the drains on Q7. The shoot-through current will be limited to a maximum of 12.6 volts ÷ 100 Ω = 126 mA. If that is too much choose a 1 kΩ resistor etc.. The added resistance will slightly slow down turn on or off but, given that you are only switching at 1 Hz and the gate capacitance of Q2 is only circa 3 nF, a response time of less than 5 μs isn't going to be a worry.

But if you fix the main problem using a BJT level shifter, this problem goes away.

### Load volt-drop

[image]

If you can live with Q2's volt-drop of 40 mV when the load takes 10 amps then you're basically good to go. That's a typical value and may be twice this amount across a batch of devices.

### MOSFET leakage (\$I_{DSS}\$) into load

When Q2 is off, it might produce typically 1 μA into the load but, again, this is a typical value and it might be as high as 100 μA. If this isn't going to cause activation of some low power circuits in the load then fine.

Comment: Thank you. Considering the above points and given the cost and space, I decided to go with TI's integrated smart high side switch for my use case.

Comment: @viru_s OK but it might be a good idea to mention which product you chose for future reference for anyone coming along later - they might be interested in your particular solution.

Comment: I decided to go with TPS2HB16-Q1. :)

Answer (score 0):

Drawing the proper symbols for your dual FET makes it easier to understand:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpnJMD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When VIN is 3.3V the top PFET (M2) will still have -5..-9V Vgs which means it will be always ON. Also 3.3V is not enough to turn M1 ON. Thus it will not work.

**Solution:**

If you want fast switching, use an integrated low-side MOSFET driver, [like this one](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/240/IX4310T-1839211.pdf). Make sure you double check everything: input logic levels must match your 3V3 signal, min/max supply voltage, etc.

If you don't want fast switching, then any simple schematic with BJTs will do, like [this one](https://hackaday.com/2016/12/13/ask-hackaday-dude-wheres-my-mosfet/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bobflux. I have decided to go with integrated high side switch from TI.